# Wordpress и интернет-эквайринг

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, ecommerce

Появился вопрос, возможно ли подключение интернет-эквайринга к магазину на wordpress (woocommerce, wp ecommerce, wp-shop — не так важно)? Существуют ли какие-то готовые решения?

Answer (score 2):

Ну вопрос в том, через кого делать эквайринг. Есть платежные интеграторы, обеспечивающие прием платежей всевозможными способами, включая и банковские карты.

Например [Платрон](http://www.platron.ru/info/tech/) у него есть даже готовые модули под WordPress. Вроде и процент не большой, но с ними сам не работал, не знаю. Я работаю для процессинга карт с rbkmoney.ru, с ними правда по бумагам для договора геморно. И модулей готовых у них вроде нет.

Comment: Не, в данном случае я спрашивал именно про работу напрямую с банком. Вот нашел у Тинькофф https://t.tinkoff.ru/ , написано "Поддерживаем 1С-Битрикс, OpenCart, MODX, NetCat, UMI, Amiro и другие популярные CMS." — я написал им в техподдержку, есть ли интеграция с вордпрессом, пока не ответили. Еще есть какой-то РФИ Банк http://rfibank.ru/electronic-commerce/online/ , там есть поддержка интеграции с вукоммерс и вп икоммерс, но я не уверен в его надежности.

Comment: Альфу не смотрели. я хз что там у них, но они сильно на электронные технологии упор делают

Comment: Альфа-банк ответили сегодня, у них есть страница касательно сабжа: https://engine.paymentgate.ru/ecommerce/ . Тинькофф молчит.